# What reactions involving hydrazine, dinitrogen tetroxide and possibly a contaminant can produce a salt?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, fuel

Hydrazine $\ce{N2H4}$ and dinitrogen tetroxide $\ce{N2O4}$ form a hypergolic fuel and oxidizer pair widely used in spacecraft including [Akatsuki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akatsuki_(spacecraft)) (あかつき, 暁, "Dawn") also known as the Venus Climate Orbiter (VCO) and Planet-C.

Wikipedia [states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine#Hydrazinium_salts):

> Hydrazine can be monoprotonated to form various solid salts of the hydrazinium cation ($\ce{N2H5+}$) by treatment with mineral acids. A common salt is hydrazinium sulfate, $\ce{[N2H5]HSO4}$, also called hydrazine sulfate. Hydrazine sulfate was investigated as a treatment of cancer-induced cachexia, but proved ineffective.
>
> Double protonation gives the hydrazinium dication ($\ce{H3NNH3^2+}$), of which various salts are known

A [comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/how-did-salt-prevent-akatsukis-insertion-burn#comment125603_38951) below the Space SE question [How did salt prevent Akatsuki's insertion burn?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38951/12102) says:

> Every article I see seems to parrot the same thing. I'm guessing this is yet another translation issue (Japanese to English) and the deposits are a hydrazine reaction product... which you could call a "salt". It's an interesting failure case that I hadn't heard of, thanks for the question.

**Question:** Are there possible reaction products from hydrazine and dinitrogen tetroxide alone that could form an *ionic assembly of cations and anions* and considered [a salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(chemistry)), or would this require some additional contaminant, perhaps water or some organic material to be involved?

Comment: How about with the reaction chamber and nozzle? Of what are they made?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I've annotated the image from [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38955/12102) here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMImf.png I've mentioned "water, or some organic material contamination" in the question because these are common contaminations that can come from a wide variety of sources, and I think you are right that can include the reaction chamber and nozzle. Water could be (and probably is) a reaction product and could be plentiful, but my knowledge of chemistry is low and I don't know if that's enough to make something that might be considered a salt.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik The valve could potentially be pretty far away from them in terms of tubing, but I don't know much about rocket engines or what keeps the high pressure from the combustion chamber from pushing reaction products upstream in this case.

Comment: BTW, you might enjoy reading *Ignition! An  Informal  History  of Liquid  Rocket  Propellants," by John  D.  Clark, https://library.sciencemadness.org/library/books/ignition.pdf