# Does the explosion of TNT include oxidation?

Tags: explosives, organic-oxidation

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/39456/rocket-explosion-compared-to-kt-of-tnt-has-one-ever-knocked-something-over-at-a?noredirect=1#comment127560_39456) below the question [Rocket explosion compared to kT of TNT; has one ever knocked something over at a distance?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39456/12102) suggests that

> ...TNT includes it's own oxidizer...

Explosion isn't the same as combustion and you don't need to add a separate oxidizer to an explosive for it to do its thing.

But *technically speaking* does the explosion of TNT include any steps that could be considered as oxidative? Can some intermediate products be considered to be acting as oxidizers?

Comment: currently unanswered Rocket-related questions: [What reactions involving hydrazine, dinitrogen tetroxide and possibly a contaminant can produce a salt?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/121517/16035) and also [Approximate magnetic susceptibility of these liquid propellants?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47455/16035)  Still not sure I have a complete answer to [Why would red fuming nitric acid become white fuming nitric acid if left out at low temperature?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/81603/16035) either.

Comment: It is not about intermediate products at all. Yes, TNT itself acts as an oxidizer. And as a reducer too.

Comment: That's just disproportionation, nothing special, really.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3 nitrogroups of TNT are rich of oxygen, but the aromatic ring has only carbon and hydrogen atoms.

Therefore oxygen of nitrogroups oxidizes carbon and hydrogen atoms.

There is no principle difference between oxidation and reduction agens being separate molecules, or being different parts of the same molecule.

Note that TNT, in contrary to e.g nitroglycerine, is oxygen deficient, so the amount of available oxygen is not enough for complete oxidation to water and carbon dioxide.

[TNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT#Explosive_character):

$$\ce{2 C7H5N3O6 -> 3 N2 + 5 H2O + 7 CO + 7 C}$$
or
$$\ce{2 C7H5N3O6 -> 3 N2 + 5 H2 + 12 CO + 2 C}$$

Nitroglycerine

$$\ce{4 C3H5N3O9 -> 6 N2 + 10 H2O + 12 CO2 +  O2 }$$

Comment: Second equation for TNT should rather be with CO2 and C - probably most accurate. Definitely no H2 there, sooner there would be only C then any gaseous hydrogen.

Comment: @Mithoron That may be questionable, as a mix of CO and H2 is/was industrially produced by reaction of gaseous H2O with hot coke. Independently, both reactions are mentioned in the Wikipedia TNT page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TNT#Explosive_character

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja410020f may shed some light on this, but is paywalled :(

Comment: Note I am not an expert in chemistry of explosives. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_explosive particularly section Balancing chemical explosion equations.

Comment: Thing is all this looks like equations/ calculations wrote from top of a head. I guess just mentioning that these are simplified/borderline examples would be okayish as question doesn't ask about it.

Comment: See also https://fas.org/man/dod-101/navy/docs/es310/chemstry/chemstry.htm

Comment: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-86682-1_2 Thermodynamics of Explosions :  .....Direct products from a chemical explosive include the usual combustion products of carbon dioxide (CO2), carbon monoxide (CO), and water vapor (H2O), and molecular nitrogen (N2). They may also include molecular hydrogen (H2) and molecular oxygen (O2), along with nitric oxide (NO).....